# Passing cookies from Flask backend to Jinja and getting values from previous session

Tags: python, flask, cookies, jinja2, session-cookies

I'm trying to make sorting and pagination on a Flask/Jinja page. Everything works fine until I want to preserve sorting while changing pagination.
On the backend I save it all to cookies as in the example:

```
response = make_response(render_template('elements.html', elements=sorted_elements))
        response.set_cookie('sort_by_cookie', value=sort_by, path='/')
        response.set_cookie('page_size_cookie', value=page_size, path='/')
        return response
```

and then I read it on a Jinja template as follows:

```
request.cookies.get('sort_by_cookie')
request.cookies.get('page_size_cookie')
```

What happens then confuses me a lot.
When I check the cookies in a browser's console everything looks fine, values are exactly as they should be. But when I read cookies like in a provided example -> request.cookies.get('sort_by_cookie') I get the cookies from previous session.

In other words, when I'm accessing my page for the very first time after setting up the cookies, all the values fetched with this code -> request.cookies.get('sort_by_cookie') ale None.
They're correctly updated when I refresh my page, but then if I change anything, they will always be delayed by one session, when in a browser's console everything is up to date.

How can I get the proper values from actual cookies?
Any help would be appreciated.